# How to add and get value from JSONArray in another class

Tags: android, arrays, return, global-variables, json

I try add JSONObject to JSONArray in this way:

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

   try {
       jsonObject.put("strefa", strefa);
       jsonObject.put("adres", adres);
       jsonObject.put("kryteria", kryteria);
       jsonObject.put("telefon", telefon);
       jsonObject.put("data", data);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   GlobalConfig config = new GlobalConfig();
   config.addJSONObject(jsonObject);
```

and get this JSONArray in this way:

```
   GlobalConfig config = new GlobalConfig();
   JSONArray jsonArray = config.getJSONArray();
```

Below is my GlobalConfig:

```
   public class GlobalConfig {

   JSONArray JsonArray = new JSONArray();

   public JSONArray getJSONArray() {

       return JsonArray;
   }

   public void addJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject) {

       JsonArray.put(jsonObject);

   }
```

Something is wrong. For example I try take a length of this array and I receive size 0. How can I return a JSONArray?

Comment: Use intents to pass data. That would be easier.

Comment: I cant, because I need to have access from any activity and Service.

Answer (score 0):

this creates new object

`GlobalConfig config = new GlobalConfig();`

results make a new array.. 
try this way :

```
GlobalConfig config = new GlobalConfig();
config.addJSONObject(jsonObject);
JSONArray jsonArray = config.getJSONArray();
```

Comment: I want to have an empty array to which I have access from any activity. It has to be Global Array like Global variable. In first activity create is jsonobject wich is added to the array and in other activity I want get this object. This is not resolve my problem.

Comment: OK, I know. I had to use static type of variable: private static JSONArray JsonArray = new JSONArray(); solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, ignoring the whole "to json or not to json" issue, your problem seems to be essentially "how do I create a singleton"..

There are lots of ways to implement a singleton pattern, but the two that are likely to be most convenient for you from what I can understand of your situation are:

1. Use the application object to hold your GlobalConfig object
2. Implement a "classic" java singleton

Both have good and bad points; I'm not going to go into the details of implementing a custom application object, you can find out how to do that here: [Android Application Object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

You could implement a "classic" java singleton like this:

```
public class GlobalConfig {
     private JSONArray JsonArray = new JSONArray();

     // This holds our shared instance of GlobalConfig
     private static GlobalConfig staticInstance;

     // Declare a private constructor to prevent accidentally using "new GlobalConfig"
     private GlobalConfig() {};

     // Use GlobalConfig.getInstance() to get your GlobalConfig
     public static GlobalConfig getInstance() {
       // We create a new instance only on the first use of getInstance
       if (staticInstance == null) {
        staticInstance = new GlobalConfig();
       }
       // Always return the same instance.. singleton!
       return staticInstance;
     }


   public JSONArray getJSONArray() {

       return JsonArray;
   }

   public void addJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject) {

       JsonArray.put(jsonObject);

   }
```

So whenever you need to access your GlobalConfig object, use

```
GlobalConfig config = GlobalConfig.getInstance()
```

or if you prefer, you can do something like:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = GlobalConfig.getInstance().getJSONArray();
```

The key to it is there is a static instance of GlobalConfig (a singleton) which is always returned by GlobalConfig.getInstance() which makes it accessible to any activity etc. Essentially it is a global variable.. However. This also means it can be difficult to release and can exist for the entire lifespan of the dalvik VM (even between launches of your app; watch out for that..)

Hope this helps.